Не работает Filepicker на IOS в flet Python
Всем привет, проблема такая: Запускаю Filepicker для считывания файлов, на всех системах (Windows, Android) работает, на IOS нет. Вопрос в чем может быть проблема и как её решить?
Добавляется он вот так:
filepicker = FilePicker()
page.overlay.clear()
page.overlay.append(filepicker)

Запускается с помощью кнопки
async def add_photo(self, _):
    self.filepicker.pick_files()

Помогите пж, мб кто-то сталкивался с данной проблемой
